# width as percent of offsetParent

Tags: css

Is there a pure CSS solution to specify the width of an element to be a percent of the offsetParent?

I have to provide a piece of HTML as a template which is rendered multiple times within a container. The template I provide itself is wrapped into another div element before placing into the container and I don't have an option to modify either the container or the wrapper. I can only provide the HTML template.

The final HTML structure would look like

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;position:relative;"> <!-- container -->
            <div> <!-- wrapper -->
                <div style="width:20%;"> <!-- template -->
                    Hello world 1
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div> <!-- wrapper -->
                <div style="width:20%;"> <!-- template -->
                    Hello world 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am looking for a way to tell this template to occupy a percent of the container, not the wrapper.

Comment: is there any illustration you can provide if you dont want to provide more code?

Comment: @Crystal, just updated the post with a sample html snippet.

Comment: is there a class or id on the div that you are saying that you can't edit? I'm still getting confused on what you want to happen. If i'm understanding it right the parent element is 100% and you want to change it to 20% or any percentage?

Comment: The top most div (direct child of body) is the container div. This is the offsetParent of all the template divs and there are in between wrapper divs. I only have control over the html for the template divs. When I specify width of 20% for these divs, it is taken as 20% of the wrapper divs and not the container div.

Comment: an illustration will work for me more i think. in script you can wrap them all so you can control it, if it is small portion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead `width: 20%` you can use `width: 20vw;`.

**with width vw**

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  position:relative;
}
.ch {
  background: gray;
  padding:20px;
  width: 20vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container"> <!-- container -->
            <div> <!-- wrapper -->
                <div class="ch ch1" > <!-- template -->
                    Hello world 1
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div> <!-- wrapper -->
                <div class="ch ch2"> <!-- template -->
                    Hello world 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**with width %**

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  position:relative;
}
.ch {
  background: gray;
  padding:20px;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container"> <!-- container -->
            <div> <!-- wrapper -->
                <div class="ch ch1" > <!-- template -->
                    Hello world 1
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div> <!-- wrapper -->
                <div class="ch ch2"> <!-- template -->
                    Hello world 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that because the container div may not be occupying the entire viewport width and I want the template div to be a percentage of whatever the container div occupies.